# Spring security: How to manually create session

Tags: spring-security, spring-social

I have HttpClient calling a Spring Social app. Because when I'm creating a connection to a service provider (e.g Facebook) calling the ConnectController Spring Social generates a OAUTH2_STATE_ATTRIBUTE attribute and saves it to the session. In my case at the point I'm calling the ConnectController I have no existing session and therefore ConnectSupport#buildOAuth2Url method cannot associate the state value with my client (i.e. there is no session).

So basically I need to establish a session before to call the ConnectController. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[`HttpServletRequest.getSession()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29):

> Returns the current session associated with this request, or if the request does not have a session, **creates one**.